# How to force the user to insert username & password when doing "back" and then "forward" in a Browser?

Tags: java, security, jsp, session, web-applications

Consider the following events (Bank login) :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What happens here is :

```
- user logs in 
- reaches a new page 
- hits back
- hits forward
- reaches the same page
```

1. How can I make the user to hit his username & password when he tries to hit forward and reach the old page that he came from ?
2. Is it possible to disable completely the back/forward option ?

Here's some code :

Login JSP :

```
<!-- Bank Application in JAVA -->
<!-- Updates : the DB now is using Hibernate for the SQL queries -->
<!-- 2014 version updates -->

<%@ page language="java" 
    contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head><title>Bank application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Web Bank application</th></tr>
</table>
<br/>


<!-- JS Code to make sure that the user MUST enter something in the login page -->
<script>
function verifyEmptyString()
{
    var username = document.forms["loginForm"]["username"].value;
    var password = document.forms["loginForm"]["password"].value;

    if (username == null || username == '' || password == null || password == '')
    {
        alert("Both Username and Password are required !");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}     
</script>


<fieldset>
  <legend>Login Page - please enter your Username and Password</legend>

  <form onsubmit="return verifyEmptyString(this)" id="loginForm" action="loginPage" method="post" > 
  <!-- note we use here a paragraph & font size -->
  <!-- Notice we use a Required field !!! -->

    <p style="font-size:15px">  <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">*</span> Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br> </p>
    <p style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">*</span>  Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br> </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

</body></html>
```

The servlet of the login :

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import model.Person;

import db.Database;


/**
 * When the user runs for the first time the bank application , he must first enter username & password 
 * and make a proper login into the system .
 * @author Administrator
 *
 */
@WebServlet("/loginPage")        // this is the name of the servlet 

public class LoginPage extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String EMPLOYEE = "Employee";
    private static final String CLIENT = "Client";
    private static final String MANAGER = "Manager";
    private static final String ADMIN = "Administrator";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        synchronized(session) 
        {

            String atrib = (String) session.getAttribute("loginFlag");

            // create a new connection to mysql database  , with this we put the new client in the database 
            Database myDabatase = null;
            Person personDb = null;

            try 
            {
                myDabatase = new Database();  // creating a database
            } 

            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  

            // create a new database 

            if (atrib == null)                  // then this is the first run of the program 
            {
                myDabatase.deleteDatabase();           // delete previous database 

            }

            myDabatase.createDatabaseAndTables();  // create the tables of the database

            ////////////// Adding people with permissions into the bank database 


            /**
             * if atrib == null , this means that this is the first time 
             * that we run the current session . 
             * 
             * if atrib != null , then this is NOT the first time that this session 
             * is is reaching the current servlet 
             */
            if (atrib == null)
            {       
                // add employees and clients of the bank 

                returnValue = myDabatase.
                        addNewPerson("Johnny", "Cordel" , "South-Africa" , "22421" , "cole" , "cole" , CLIENT);

                returnValue = myDabatase.
                        addNewPerson("Jason", "Bourne" , "Australia" , "32323" , "jason" , "jason" , EMPLOYEE);

                // add a manager 

                returnValue = myDabatase.
                        addNewPerson("Jacky", "Chan" , "Japan" , "29489324" , "jake" , "jake" , MANAGER);
                if (returnValue == false)
                    throw new ServletException();  // if we got here - the person wasn't added


                // add an initial account to the bank 
                //      _accountNumber , _currentState , _holderIdnumber

                myDabatase.openNewAccount("0123",120, "87534");
                myDabatase.openNewAccount("0123",120, "12345");
                myDabatase.openNewAccount("001234",-210, "22421");
                myDabatase.openNewAccount("00212",-4343, "32323");
            }



            // get the username that the user entered into the text box 
            String username = request.getParameter("username");  

            // get the password entered into the text box 
            String password = request.getParameter("password");

            try 
            {
                 // check if the client that entered the login details of Username & Password 
                 // exists in the database

                // find the user with the given "password" & "username" 
                personDb = myDabatase.verifyRegisteredPerson(username, password);   
            } 
            catch (SQLException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            // making sure to use the person the next time we reach the same page

            session.setAttribute("name", personDb);  

            // then the person exists in the db  , forwarding to the right place - first check if the person is a client 

            // according to the credentials of the person , 4 options goes here : 
            // manager , client , admin , or - employee

            if (personDb != null)
            {

                session.setAttribute("loginFlag", "turndOn"); 
                ///////////// client 

                if (personDb.getStatus().equals(CLIENT) == true)  
                {
                     String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/results/client/clientPage.jsp";
                     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(addressPath);
                     dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }




                ///////////// manager 
                // person is a manager - redirecting to the Manager's page 

                else if (personDb.getStatus().equals(MANAGER) == true)
                {
                    session.setAttribute("managerLogin", "turnOn");
                     String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/results/manager/managerPage.jsp";
                     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(addressPath);
                     dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }


                //////////////////// administrator 

                // person is the administrator of the bank - forwarding to the admin's page

                else if (personDb.getStatus().equals(ADMIN) == true)
                {
                     String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/results/admin/adminPage.jsp";
                     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(addressPath);
                     dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }


                ////////////////// employee

                // person is an employee - forwarding to the employee's page
                else if (personDb.getStatus().equals(EMPLOYEE) == true)
                {
                    String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/results/employee/employeePage.jsp";
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(addressPath);
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }



            }



                ////////////// the user how entered the password & username doesn't exist

            else if (personDb == null) // then the client doesn't exist , and isn't registered 
            {
                     String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/results/login-failed.jsp";
                     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(addressPath);
                     dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }


        } // end session

        // closing database 

    } // end method get 


}
```

Comment: are you closing the session when you hit "back" button?. pages usually show a - "are you sure you want to logout?. Your session will expire" kind of message.

Comment: This is actually a problem that is non-trivial to fix.

Comment: Apply a global no-cache and must-revalidate filter on the http requests, and create a page flow. If the user does something unattended , persist relevant data, invalidate and close the session. That should work, as it does well with jsf.

Comment: Need any further info in my answer?

Comment: @SilverlightFox: No , I'm good . Thanks(chosen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [something such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705994/413180) where each navigation or form submission POSTs to the next page.

e.g.

```
<form method="https://www.example.com/requestHandler">

<input type="action" value="navigateToLoginForm" />
<input type="token" value="qwerty1234" />

</form>
```

As each navigation action is a POST, the browser will ask the user to resubmit their data upon history navigation (eg. back button). If you receive an already used `token` value you will know the user is not following your preset flow and you can ask them to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Define the flow of you pages and destroy the session if the user does not follow the flow.