# Which is more efficient/faster? Storing/extracting info in Session Storage vs Hidden Fields within the html using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, session-storage

Which is more efficient/faster? Storing/extracting info in Session Storage vs Hidden Fields within the html using JavaScript?

Surprisingly I had trouble finding information on this with a focus entirely on speed/efficiency.

Comment: It shouldn't matter in 99% of situations, is this *actually* a bottleneck you're running into?

Comment: just check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423214/hidden-input-fields-vs-session-vs-cookie

Comment: @CertainPerformance If i can get confirmation that one is slightly more faster, I'd make the effort to design future implementations based around that method.

Comment: It's not worth it. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Comment: Lets say someone comes across this question *actually* running into this bottleneck, I hope someone can answer this.